# How "YEAR" data type take only 1 byte in mysql server

Tags: mysql

In Mysql server *"YEAR"* data type range is  **1000 to 9999**.If we convert 9999 to binary it take **2byte** then how mysql server able to store it in  **1 byte**

Answer (score 8):

The initial assertion is incorrect.

The [YEAR type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html) *only* supports the years from 1901..2155, inclusive. (In comparisson, the [DATE and DATETIME types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) support the range of years from 1000..9999.)

> [YEAR values can be specified] in the range 1901 to 2155.

It only takes one byte to store the distinct integers (2155-1901+1 = 255) in this range. The full year, which is limited to 1901..2155, is computed by using an implicit *offset* from 1900: `year = 1900 + stored_year_byte`.

MySQL also supports an "invalid year" sentinel value (0), displayed as "0000", which is why a year of 1900 is not allowed.

---

Answer (score 3):

The YEAR type is a `1-byte` type used to represent year values. It can be declared as YEAR(2) or YEAR(4) to specify a display width of two or four characters. If no width is given the default is four characters

`YEAR(4) and YEAR(2)` have different display format, but have the same range of values.

For `4-digit format`, MySQL displays YEAR values in YYYY format, with a range of 1901 to 2155, or 0000.

For `2-digit format`, MySQL displays only the last two (least significant) digits; for example, 70 (1970 or 2070) or 69 (2069).

You can specify YEAR values in a variety of formats:

```
String length           |Range
4-digit string          | '1901' to '2155'.
4-digit number          |1901 to 2155.
1- or 2-digit string    |'0' to '99'. Values in the ranges '0' to '69' and '70' to '99' are converted to YEAR values in the ranges 2000 to 2069 and 1970 to 1999.
1- or 2-digit number    |1 to 99. Values in the ranges 1 to 69 and 70 to 99 are converted to YEAR values in the ranges 2001 to 2069 and 1970 to 1999.
```

***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html***

***http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/data-types.html#year***